# pytorch - RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (256x512 and 256x512) for identical sizes

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create a CNN that obtains at least 80% accuracy on CIFAR10 data in 20 epochs.

```
class HWCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_channels, num_classes):
        super(HWCNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(num_channels, 32, 3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2)

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2)

        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv6 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(2)

        nn.Flatten()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256*4*4, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 512)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 10)

    def forward(self, X):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(X))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv5(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv6(x))
        x = self.pool3(x)
        x = x.reshape(-1, 256*4*4)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

```
import torch.optim as optim

cuda = torch.device('cuda')
model = HWCNN(3, 10)
model.to(cuda)

optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
epochs = 20

train_losses = []
valid_losses = []

best_valid_acc = 0

for epoch in range(0, epochs):
    
    print('Epoch number ', epoch + 1)
    
    train_loss = train(model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    train_accuracy = accuracy(model, train_loader)
    
    valid_loss = validate(model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    valid_losses.append(valid_loss)
    valid_accuracy = accuracy(model, valid_loader)
    if best_valid_acc < valid_accuracy:
        best_valid_acc = valid_accuracy
    
    training_stats(train_loss, train_accuracy, valid_loss, valid_accuracy)
print('Best validation accuracy', best_valid_acc)
```

If I run this, I get `RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (256x512 and 256x512)`. But the matrices have the same size, 256x512. Why is this happening? I tried modifying the `reshape` arguments as well, but I can't get this to work. Any ideas? Thank you, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring FC layers works like `nn.Linear(num_in_features, num_out_features)`; see [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html). In other words, you're telling `fc1` to start with 256*4*4 input features produce 512 output features. Then `fc2` tries to start with 256 input features and produces 512 output features. This is a mismatch, since you're telling `fc2` to expect 256 inputs but you actually passed it 512 inputs.

If you fix this mistake, you'll immediately see a new error: `fc2` currently returns 512 output features, but then `fc3` expects only 256 inputs.

You can fix both problems at once by replacing your line `self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 512)` with `self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 256)`.

**Edit:** You should also remove the line `x = self.fc2(x)`. As is, your code is applying `fc2` twice in a row. I'm assuming you just made a typo, since two consecutive FC layers are no better than one if you don't include an activation function like ReLU in between. This is also the cause of the new error mentioned in your comment, since the first `fc2` call spits out 256 features and then the second `fc2` call expects 512 inputs.

---

Bonus debugging tip: Try writing

```
print(model(torch.zeros((3,38,38))))
```

at any point after you've defined `model`. That will produce an immediate error if you have dimensions mismatches like the ones in this question. Then you can comment out the last several lines in `forward()` and see if the error goes away. This way you can quickly narrow down which layer is causing the dimension mismatch. Finding the bug becomes much easier once you know for sure exactly which line is causing the problem.

---

Incidentally, the "shapes cannot be multiplied" error is referring to [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition). If matrix A has dimensions m x n and matrix B has dimensions r x s, then the product A*B is only defined if n = r, which isn't satisfied for the dimensions in the error message.

Comment: This solves the matrix multiplication error, however now I'm getting ```RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (128x256 and 512x256)```

Comment: Edited the answer with a fix for this bug + advice on how to track down these kinds of bugs in future :)